# Figuring out value that a memory address points to

Tags: c++, c, gdb

I'm new to C/C++ development. Anyways, I'm using Eclipse CDT to debug through v8 code and saw some variables that have the following values :-

[image]

a) expr->target_ has a value 0x95b2538

expr->target_ expanded view as requested

[image]

b) expr->value_ has a value 0x95b2580

I think both are memory address : 0x95b2538 / 0x95b2580.

My questions are :

1. how do i figure out what value(s) that memory address (expr->target_) 0x95b2538 points to?
2. can i use Expression window to show this value?

Thank you

Comment: Whatever "v8" is, it's probably internal or private variables/class members. Examining the header files will probably reveal their purpose, if it's apparent.

Comment: The expression above is trying to assign a number (that variables called "value_" has to a variable called "target_),  I looking for the exact values for these two memory address. If not mistaken, _target should be x, and value_ is 1. 

Just need to be sure. Thanks :)

Comment: Press those little triangles on the left

Comment: Anton - i did. it give me pretty much the same thing (0x95b2538 / 0x95b2580). Unfortunately i can only upload the screenshot of the values once i have access to my home laptop.

Comment: The expr->value_ is a pointer variable-- which as you say points to a memory address.  To get the value it points to, you want to display "*expr->value_".  Not sure how do this under eclipse/CDT though.

Comment: Yeap, will be great if anyone can help me figure this out under Eclipse.

Comment: @kepung: Wait before posting until you have the access you need to the detail we need.

Comment: ok posted the expanded view.

Comment: I kept on expanding and expanding the tree/triangles, and i get what i was looking for.

@AntonSavin thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To see the value pointed by a pointer variable, use `*`

Assuming `pointer` points to `int`

```
printf("address in pointer: %p\n", (void*)pointer);
printf("value at the place `pointer` points to: %d\n", *pointer);
//                                              %d for int
```

If instead `pointer` points to another pointer

```
printf("address in pointer: %p\n", (void*)pointer);
printf("value at the place `pointer` points to: %p\n", (void*)*pointer);
//                                              %p for pointer
```

The thing to remember is that the conversion specification in the `printf()` conversion string must match the type of value in the argument.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Anton Savin

Press those little triangles on the left –  Anton Savin

I kept on expanding and expanding the tree/triangles, and i get what i was looking for.